# V7 hard fork inputs sorting

Tags: transaction-data, hard-fork

I've seen that the new hard fork requires the inputs to be sorted. I already had some transactions rejected from my testnet node due to this rule.
So, the question is:
How are the inputs supposed to be sorted? 
I need to sort the mixin offsets from min to max?
Is there some definition of this rule somewhere?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The sort is to be done on key images. See src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_tx_utils.cpp from line 321 on current master.

Are those rejected transactions created by monero-wallet-cli or monero-wallet-gui ? If so, please file a bug on github.